# Read an excel file into R containing columns mixing dates and characters

Tags: r, excel, date

I want to read an excel file with historical data into R that contains the following columns:

```
  date1      date2     
    
1 1926-12-31 1930-11-08
2 1898-xx-xx 1899-11-30
```

The excel format is general and the columns contains dates and text. However, when I read the file, R returns:

```
  date1      date2     
     
1 9862       11270     
2 1898-xx-xx 1899-11-30
```

I understand that reading date formats from excel into R can cause issues, but in this case the problem is a bit special since the columns mix proper dates (like 1926-12-31), historical dates (pre 1899) and characters (like 1898-xx-xx). Is it possible to just read the file into R and keep the original format?

Comment: Yes, most functions that read in csv files will allow you to specify the column data type as "character" which should read in exactly what is saved there.  You can then go on to manipulate or amend as required.  What function are you using?

Comment: I'm using read_excel() from the readlxl package. I used col_types = "text" but that didn't change anything.

Comment: The data in your second image is how the data is actually stored in Excel.  The 'date format' in the first image is just how it's displayed.  Try the `janitor` package with its function convert_to_date() which can cope with both excel date style and other styles.  Then you will just need to sort the xx-xx ones.